# Problem with stream and firebase Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I have a StreamBuilder that is meant to be getting me a list of documents from firestore based on a variable being passed through, though I am getting the above error.

StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: DatabaseService.getFeedPosts(widget.currentUserId),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    // Loader Animation Widget
                    Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
                    Text('Finding tasks'),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final documents = snapshot.data.docs;

              return ListView(
                  children: documents
                      .map(
                        (doc) => TaskList(
                          currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
                          task: doc['id'],
                          user: doc['ownerId'],
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList());
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print('Error');
              return Text('It\'s Error!');
            }
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Unable to  find any tasks'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
```

Firebase query

```
static Stream<QuerySnapshot> getFeedPosts(String userId) {
    return tasksRef
        .where('authorId', isEqualTo: userId)
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [`data()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot/data.html) method from [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html) before using the `[]` operator:

```dart
return ListView(
  children: documents
  .map(
    (doc) => TaskList(
      currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
      task: doc.data()['id'],
      user: doc.data()['ownerId'],
    ),
  )
  .toList(),
);
```

Comment: I am doing that in model already but do I need to do it again?

Comment: I believe you expect a map from Firestore and try to access the value of the entries whose keys are `id` and `ownerId`. However, `doc` is a `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. To access the map from `doc`, you need to retrieve it first and that would be using `data()` method.